# How to SELECT / Query Whole Numbers only

Tags: sql, oracle

Would you know If i can select only whole numbers?
I don't want to round off the values.

For example this is select * from Table_1 below

| Numbers | Team |
| --- | --- |
| 10.5 | A |
| 12.12 | B |
| 23 | C |

I would do like
select * from Table_1
where NUMBERS is ;

Expected output below

| Numbers | Team |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | C |

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the data type of the column Numbers?

Answer (score 3):

The function [`TRUNC()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm) truncates a number without rounding:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1
WHERE TRUNC("Numbers") = "Numbers";
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ffdeff56c350f7f9b1f20f11b91be7be).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ROUND` function to filter (rather than to display) the values:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_1
WHERE  ROUND(numbers) = numbers;
```

You could also use the `FLOOR`, `CEIL` or `TRUNC` functions instead of `ROUND`.

Or, you could use the `MOD` function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_1
WHERE  MOD(numbers, 1) = 0;
```

*(And you could apply a function-based index to `MOD(number, 1)` if you wanted to improve performance.)*

---

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 (Numbers, Team) AS
SELECT 10.5,  'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12.12, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 23,    'C' FROM DUAL;
```

All the options output:

> | NUMBERS | TEAM |
> | --- | --- |
> | 23 | C |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=480a9086bb5af59886f61b7e35e71706)*